# Call JQuery bootstrap events parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I call an event using jquery, how can I know that the function has parameters or not, and what can I parse to those parameters. Example

```
$("#id").on('show.bs.modal', function () { });
$("#id").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { });
```

In the example above, I passed the parameter e. The two syntax above can work well.

Comment: The handler always accepts an `event` parameter. See http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Comment: `I passed the parameter e.`. Not really, you created a function that accepts a parameter `e`.  You could name this whatever you wanted,   `function(whatever)` or nothing at all as you have seen, what gets sent into that parameter you would need to read the documentation. For something as simple as a modal been shown I doubt there will be anything useful been sent.

Comment: @Philisonstrike: I understand that I have to look up the documentation for the event/function I'm going to use. But what if I can't find the manual? I'm using bootstrap events just as an example.

Comment: @Keith: I understand that I can use any name as a parameter. In my example, I can pass the parameter "e" or not. If I don't know that parameter exists, the next operation I will do is retrieve the data / value that I need manually. But if I know there are parameters and these parameters can be useful and I can use them for the next operation, then I can look up what those parameters are.

Comment: If `jQuery` has some good Typescript (if using TS) or JSDoc support, then you can often get good code insight.   Other than that you should look at the documentation, if something is not documented then it could change in future updates, so relying on inspecting the arguments at runtime is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using jQuery's on method to bind an event handler, you can determine whether the function has parameters or not by checking the number of arguments received by the handler function. You can use the arguments.length property to get the number of arguments passed to the function.

Here's an example of how you can check if the event handler function has parameters:

```js
$("#id").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        // The handler has parameters
        var e = arguments[0];
        // Access and use the parameter (e) as needed
    } else {
        // The handler does not have parameters
    }
});
```